# Pointer to a member of class

Tags: c++, function-pointers

In my class, If I want to point to a member of class,

```
struct S
{
     static int get();
     int do_something();
     int x;
};
```

I do,

```
int (*p)() = S::get;
```

Unfortunately this doesn't for non-static member

```
int (*p)() = S::do_something; // error
```

Since, a static member function is an ordinary function, and from the quote I came around below states that a non-static member function is also a ordinary function so why wouldn't it work? what does it mean?

> (9.2/10) [Note: the type of a nonstatic member function is an ordinary
>   function type, and the type of a nonstatic data member is an ordinary
>   object type. There are no special member function types or data member
>   types. ]

Comment: This is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439540/function-pointer-to-class-member-function-problems

Comment: A must read to understand the concept : [Pointers to member functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html)

Answer (score 5):

Non-static member functions are **not** ordinary functions. You cannot form free pointers to them.

The only permissible way to refer to a non-static member function is through a **pair** of an instance pointer/reference and a pointer-to-member-function:

```
S * p = &theobject;
int (S::*ptmf)() = &S::do_something;

return (p->*ptmf)();
```

Unlike member *objects* (to which you can very well form a free pointer, e.g. `&theobject.x`), member functions are more complicated, because you need to account for virtual functions: If `S` is a polymorphic base class and `p` is a pointer-to-base and `do_something()` is virtual, then the above example should perform the correct type of dispatch. A simple free function pointer cannot do this.

<sub>(Moreover, the standard does not specify how each underlying implementation of member functions is implemented, so this detail is never exposed to the user. Typically it'll be something like `int S_mangled_name_do_something(S *);`, but that's not specified.)</sub>

Here are some related answers of mine on the subject: [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8198062/596781), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6908641/596781).

Comment: Can you refer to non-static member **variables** in a similar fashion as pointers?

Comment: @anddero: Yes, pointers-to-member can also point to data members. For example, given `struct X { int a; };` you can form `int X::*p = &X::a;`. ([Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CnR9cKdo9EpPx67G).)

Answer (score 2):

The type of the function is ordinary, not the type of the function-pointer. A pointer to a  non-static member-function has to be declared like this:

```
typedef int (S::*p)() ptr_to_member_of_s;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int (S::*p)() = S::do_something;
```

a non-static member function is an ordinary function except that there is an invisible parameter this.

Comment: The invisible parameter is only the tip of the iceberg, though. Virtual dispatch is a far more serious design issue.

Comment: @KerrekSB Agreed. For virtual functions, we could use std::function with Lambda expression `Base* p = &theObject;
 std::function<int()> func = [&p]()->int{
  return p->doSomething();
 };`

Comment: No no no -- `(p->*ptfm)()` already does take care of the correct dispatch. My argument was that a member function is more than a free function with a hidden argument.